# Hiding Open Graph video post from timeline?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, video, facebook-opengraph, facebook-timeline

I am trying to post a video to Facebook using the Open Graph API without adding it to the timeline on Facebook, but so far I have been unable to find any API that allows me to do this. Is this possible with the current APIs, and if so, how?